# How do I launch the default web browser in Perl on any operating system?

Tags: perl, url, browser, default

I want to open a URL, such as `http://www.example.com/`, at the end of a Perl script. I don't want to access it with WWW::Mechanize but actually show the web page to the user in a graphical web browser.

There are ways to do this in Mac (`open URL`) and Windows, but I want a solution that works on any operating system, not just one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The second hit on ["open url" at search.cpan](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=open%20url&mode=all) brings up [Browser::Open](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Browser::Open):

```
use Browser::Open qw( open_browser );

my $url = 'http://www.google.com/';
open_browser($url);
```

If your OS isn't supported, send a patch or a bug report.

Comment: Browser::Open doesn't work for Cygwin. It only uses 'start' not 'cygstart'.

Comment: @Chloe, yes, that's [a bug in Browser::Open](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=85972).  Hopefully, it'll be fixed soon.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `$^O` variable to identify a platform and use different commands for each OS.

For example:

```
sub open_default_browser {
  my $url = shift;
  my $platform = $^O;
  my $cmd;
  if    ($platform eq 'darwin')  { $cmd = "open \"$url\"";          } # Mac OS X
  elsif ($platform eq 'linux')   { $cmd = "x-www-browser \"$url\""; } # Linux
  elsif ($platform eq 'MSWin32') { $cmd = "start $url";             } # Win95..Win7
  if (defined $cmd) {
    system($cmd);
  } else {
    die "Can't locate default browser";
  }
}

open_default_browser("http://www.example.com/");
```

Comment: It depend on where the script will be used. If it is a single script, it should use fewer external dependencies for better portability. However modules can be together with the script and in this case it is better to use `Browser::Open`.

Comment: Nicely done, though `xdg-open` seems to be available on more Linux systems than `x-www-browser`, which is not preinstalled on Fedora and CentOS, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

If installing CPAN module [Browser::Open](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Browser-Open/lib/Browser/Open.pm) is not an option or not desired, [Taras' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8869676/45375) provides a good alternative, but can be improved in the following ways:

- make the function work robustly on Windows with URLs that contain shell metacharacters such as `&` and `^`.
- on Windows, add support for the MSYS, Git Bash, and Cygwin Unix-emulation environments
- add support for additional operating systems that also have the `xdg-open` utility, namely all OSs that are [freedesktop.org](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/)-compatible, i.e., use GUIs that are X Window-based, which includes non-Linux platforms such as PC-BSD (FreeBSD-based) and OpenSolaris.

```perl
# SYNOPSIS
#   openurl <url>
# DESCRIPTION
#   Opens the specified URL in the system's default browser.
# COMPATIBILITY
#   OSX, Windows (including MSYS, Git Bash, and Cygwin), as well as Freedesktop-compliant
#   OSs, which includes many Linux distros (e.g., Ubuntu), PC-BSD, OpenSolaris...
sub openurl {
  my $url = shift;
  my $platform = $^O;
  my $cmd;
  if    ($platform eq 'darwin')  { $cmd = "open \"$url\"";       }  # OS X
  elsif ($platform eq 'MSWin32' or $platform eq 'msys') { $cmd = "start \"\" \"$url\""; } # Windows native or MSYS / Git Bash
  elsif ($platform eq 'cygwin')  { $cmd = "cmd.exe /c start \"\" \"$url \""; } # Cygwin; !! Note the required trailing space.
  else { $cmd = "xdg-open \"$url\""; }  # assume a Freedesktop-compliant OS, which includes many Linux distros, PC-BSD, OpenSolaris, ...
  if (system($cmd) != 0) {
    die "Cannot locate or failed to open default browser; please open '$url' manually.";
  }
}
```

<sup>Cygwin caveat: Bizarrely, the only way to protect the URL passed to `cmd.exe` from interpretation of chars. such as `&` and `^` is to *append a trailing space*. This works in all but one edge case, which, however, should be rare in the real world: if the URL contains something like `%FOO%` and an environment variable named `FOO` *exists*, `%FOO%` is inadvertently expanded.</sup>