# perl - Launch url in browser opening in non-default browser

Tags: perl, browser, default

I try to launch my default browser and open to a specified URL as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867262/how-do-i-launch-the-default-web-browser-in-perl-on-any-operating-system) using something like:

```
use Browser::Open qw( open_browser );

my $url = 'http://www.google.com/';
open_browser($url);
```

But it opens it in Firefox even though Chromium is set to my default browser:

[image]

How do I get it to open in Chromium?

Comment: Which operating environment is this question about? Windows, KDE, Gnome, ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl has no concept of default browser. As you can see in its [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Browser-Open/lib/Browser/Open.pm), `Browser::Open` will go down the list of known browser invocation commands and use the first one that works. Firefox apparently happens to be higher on the list than Chromium.

If you want to invoke Chromium, then just invoke Chromium yourself. Something like this should do:

```
system("chromium \"$url\"")
```

(you might have to change the name of the executable, depending on your system and `PATH`)

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I ended up using `system("chromium-browser \"$url\"")` on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.